# Problems in installing Oracle 10g database

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

While installing Oracle 10g software, at the end i got the following error message.

[image]

And then when i run SQLPlus.exe I can not sign in using Scott/Tiger username/password. I get this error message

```
"ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error"
```

Whats the issue?

Also, At the end of installation, i get this screen which says Database Control URL is .......... iSQLPlus url is ......

[image]

but when I copy/paste this url in the browser  i get

```
Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname) 

Your requested host "imccit101.imcc.ae" could not be resolved by DNS.

For assistance, contact your network support team.
```

What are these url's for and how can I use them?

Comment: I guess there's no point in asking why you are installing a database that has been out of support for years.

Comment: sadly thats the only version I have..

Comment: the latest version can be downloaded here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index-092322.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether you have the necessary services installed related to oracle. There should be service for the oracle instance and Tnslistner. If you have them try start them manually.

Comment: whats the service name for tnslistner?

Comment: I cannot exactly remember. But it should be something like OracleHOME_NAMETNSListener  which associates with your instance name. check this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e10845/admin.htm#NTQRF070

Comment: out of all Oracle services in my system, I am unable to start two of them which are `OracleOradb10g_home2iSQL*Plus` and `OracleOradb10g_home2TNSListener`. I get error message `"Window could not start the SERVICEName service on local computer. Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly"`